# Setting background image for ASP MVC devexpress button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to web development using MVC .

Is it possible to have a custom background for MVC devexpress button rather than the that of the theme

I have tried something like

```
@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
                {
                    settings.Name = "Button";
                    settings.Text = "Log In";
                    settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                    settings.ControlStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
                    settings.ControlStyle.Border.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                    settings.Images.Image.Url = "../../Content/images/lBlueButton.png";

                    settings.ToolTip = "Click for login";
                    settings.Width = 120;
                }).GetHtml()
```

But the button gets enlarged as the image is large and also the default theme  is applied.

How should I proceed?

Comment: With the DevExpress MVC toolset, there include an Icon Library which has a variety of icons you can use. To use it, you could set the appropriate icon as follows: settings.Images.Image.IconID = IconID.ZoomZoomin16x16;, for example.

Comment: Also you want to set the default theme of by calling; settings.EnableTheme = false;